# Associate metadata tags with other tags and coding references

Tags: java, mysql, design-patterns, database-design, relational-database

I have a series of tags that are to be associated to various other entities.

```
CREATE TABLE `CustomTags` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

| id | tag_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | restaurants |
| 2 | sunsets |
| 3 | business meetings |
| 4 | nature |
| 5 | snow |
| 6 | friendly gatherings |
| 7 | winter sports |

I have other tables linked with a N:N relationship with this table (i.e. there is an intermediate table that links the ids of each of the table for each relationship).
When I load the data I need to be able to add a new tag:

| id | tag_name |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | winter sports lakes |

and be able to:

1. Load the new tag and associate it with an existing tag conditionally, e.g. if I have a set of other data linked with tag_id `7` then if new data are inserted that are associated with something similar, e.g. `8`, I want to be able to group them all as one logical entity i.e. associate `<7, winter sports>` with `<8, winter sports lakes>` as in `winter sports lakes` is an extension of `winter sports`. And I would like to be able to do it conditionally, e.g. if in the end I want to remove anything associated to tag_id `8` I'd like to be able to do it without other impact.
2. I'd like to be able in the code to be able to know when I am processing, e.g. `restaurants` vs `business meeting`. Originally in the code I used hard-coded `id` but this doesn't work well because the code is coupled with the ids in the database. The original issue I was trying to avoid is to use hard-coded strings in the code, e.g. `restaurants` or `winter sports` that could end up due to a typo to cause a problem in the data. I am not sure how to be able to have the code understand what kind of data it is processing when required.

How can I set my DB tables and definitions in the code to achieve this?

Comment: @Akina: Good question, the way that it is now is that `321` is introduced as extending the overal "space" of `123` so whatever is `321` is also `123` so if it turns out that `321` was a bad choice then we can remove anything associated to `321` without affecting `123` except by "reducing" its space.

Comment: @Akina: No I don't think it is bidirectional.

Comment: @Akina: would the parent/child relationship be resolved within the application code or within SQL queries? I can't recall seeing a recursive SQL query

Comment: @Akina: and should I keep references to tag names or tag ids within the application code for more robust approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relation between tags is not bi-directional then you may use parent-child reference scheme:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `CustomTags` (
  `id` int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` INT UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `CustomTags` (`id`))
```

Your data will look like:

| id | tag_name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | restaurants | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 7 | winter sports | NULL |
| 8 | winter sports lakes | 7 |

---

If the relation is bi-directional then I'd recommend to create an entity "tags group" stored in separate table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `CustomTags` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE tags_groups (
    tag_id INT UNSIGNED,
    group_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES `CustomTags` (id)
);
```

Your data will look like:

| id | tag_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | restaurants |
| ... | ... |
| 7 | winter sports |
| 8 | winter sports lakes |

| tag_id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| ... | ... |
| 7 | 456 |
| 8 | 456 |

Comment: What about how to keep the tags within the application code? E.g should I keep the `id=7` or the string `winter sports` and use it whenever the application needs to do something specific to `winter sports`? Or is there some other approach that mitigates hardcoding either ids or strings?Or should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: @Jim I can say nothing about the app level - this is too opinion-based.

Comment: So if want to be able to keep the base tags within the application code so that the code can process things differently e.g. for `winter sports` that approach and how it should be done is opinion based? There is no specific way that is less prone to errors and maintainance?

Comment: Do you have some good example of how to load the data when the table is in that structure? I have an idea of doing recursion within the application code but I was wondering what other approaches are there and some good example

Comment: @Jim *how to load the data* This is separate question. Create new topic. Show clearly where the data should be loaded from, and with what method.